# How to solve image colors fading when uploaded in a html file

Tags: html, css

I added some images to my website and the colors in them faded out.
here is the section where I am adding one of the images in the HTML

```html
<section id="two" class="spotlight style2 right">
  <div class="image fit main"><img src="images/1111.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="content">
    <header>
      <h2>Courses & Projects</h2>
      <p>For Adults and Students</p>
    </header>
    <p>Robone team developed their own educational curriculum based on studying students’ behavior, especially students’ stress arousals and their effects on students’ understanding.</p>
    <p>One of the most unique factors of Robone is their curriculum, which is updated quarterly based on technology updates and facilities.</p>
    <p>. Moreover, Robone team design their curriculum based on a combination between international advanced course text books and elementary courses.</p>
    <ul class="actions">
      <li><a href="courses.html" class="button">Learn More</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="#four" class="goto-next scrolly">Next</a>
</section>
```

I tried using different extensions of the image (.jpg, .jpeg, .png) but still the colors fade out.

Comment: Can you add your css

Comment: did you save the image for screen RGB or CMYK?

Comment: You should add the CSS, in case there's a definition causing this. Such as a transparency, or an element above it with a transparent background.

Comment: You will either have to calm your boss down, or give us more details about the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "colors in them faded out" ? Can you also attach a screenshot and CSS

Answer (score 1):

I would comment rather than answer, but I don't have enough 'reputation'...

Try looking at style definition for .image and see if there's an opacity setting less than value of 1.

I can only guess without CSS to look at.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are (probably) facing is that your image has a (not supported) color profile. You should first convert your image to a sRGB image (safe RGB) in Photoshop or a similar program. You might experience the same 'fading' while converting. When you correct that and save as sRGB your image will show up exactly as intended. Any other color profile suffers from interpretation errors by your webbrowser/computer/device (this is partly why 'Save For Web' is invented).

> sRGB: the color profile used by most web browsers to display images on the web.

[Some background info](https://intothedarkroom.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200269555-Color-Shifting-Save-for-Web-sRGB-and-Color-Profiles-Oh-My-), and 
[some more](https://om4.com.au/client/preparing-images-color-profiles-srgb-adobe-rgb/)...